# Como buscar la siguiente coincidencia con el editor vi?

Tags: linux, vi

Estoy utilizando VI para editar archivos al momento de buscar una palabra lo hago con el comando /, pero como hago para ir a la siguiente coincidencia? por el momento vuelvo a escribir la palabra a buscar

Comment: n ( next result ) o * ( next palabra igual a la del cursor )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qué tal,

para buscar la siguiente coincidencia al editar con `vi`, solo tienes que pulsar la tecla `n`, es decir, haces tu búsqueda con el comando `/` y para seguir buscando, tecleas el comando `n` cuantas veces sea necesario para buscar en el archivo en edición.

Cuando la búsqueda alcance el final del archivo, `vi` te indicará que continuará buscando desde el inicio del archivo.